# Make rounded values add up to desired product

Tags: php, arrays

This is a programming question that will require some thinking, and could really be applied to any programming language.

Suppose you have the array:

```
$arr=array(10,7,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

This array is dynamic and could be any set of numbers.

You also have a multiplier, lets say `0.6`.

The goal is to display each number, one by one, in such a manner that they add as close to the total*multiplier as possible. In this case, the numbers add to 36, *0.6 gives you 21.6

Here's the catch:

1. You have to round each value (whole numbers only), so your real goal is to make the numbers add as close to 22 as possible.
2. You cannot use any functions to solve for the sum of the array. You can only loop through it once.

The most basic attempt would be

```
$multiplier = 0.6;
$sum=0;
foreach($arr AS $value){
$sum+=round($multiplier * $value);
}
```

But this will not work since 1*0.6 will always round to 1.

I think it is possible with something like this:

```
$multiplier = 0.6;
$sum=0;
foreach($arr AS $value){
$real=$multiplier * $value;
$rounded=round($multiplier * $value);
$sum_rounded += $rounded;
$sum_real += $real;
//Somehow compare the two sums and break the foreach 
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. What do you guys think?

Tried this:

```
$sum_real=0;
$sum_round=0;
$count=0;

foreach($rows AS $arr){
    $count+=1;
    $real_val=$arr*$multiplier;

    $sum_round+=round($real_val);
    $sum_real+=$real_val;
    $avg_round=$sum_round/$count;
    $avg_real = $sum_real/$count;

    $val = ($avg_round>$avg_real) ? floor($real_val) : round($real_val);
}
```

But did not work...I think it is getting close though.

Comment: What is your question? Where is the error? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why not loop twice? It's O(n), no big deal.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I wasn't sure where to go from the foreach loop at the end and wanted to see if you guys had any ideas.

Comment: Multiply all but the last element of the array by the multiplier, and round them, and add them up. Then calculate the difference between this and the intended sum, and use this as the replacement for the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the average for both `$sum_rounded` and `$sum_real` at the beginning of each iteration of the `foreach` loop. If the average for `$sum_rounded` is larger, use `floor()` instead of `round()`.

**EDIT:** You don't actually need to calculate the average at all, since the numbers will both be divided by the same number and that doesn't affect which one is larger. Also, add the `$value` that is about to be incremented to the comparisons.

```
foreach($arr AS $value){
  $real=$multiplier * $value;
  $rounded=round($multiplier * $value);
  if($sum_rounded + $rounded > $sum_real + $real) {
    $sum_rounded += floor($multiplier * $value);
  }
  else {
    $sum_rounded += $rounded;
  }
  $sum_real += $real;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, trying this now.

Comment: The average for $sum_rounded was always larger since the multiplier is below one...

Comment: @hellohellosharp: I updated my answer and added example code, please see if this works for you. With your example data `$sum_rounded` should be larger only twice.

Comment: Awesome! One array, one loop, and very simple! Only thing I had to add was the actual $val to be displayed in the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can talk you into looping twice.

```
$arr = array(10,7,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1);
$out = [];
$multiplier = 0.6;

$sum = round(array_sum($arr) * $multiplier); // that's a loop!

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $value = round($multiplier * $value);
    array_push($out, $value);
    $sum -= $value;
}

while ($sum > 0) {
    $sum --;
    $out[$sum] --;
}

while ($sum < 0) {
    $sum ++;
    $out[-$sum] ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1-pass method:

```
$orig_sum = 0;
$rounded_sum = 0;
$new_arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) {
  $orig_sum += $arr[$i];
  $new_elt = round($arr[$i] * $multiplier);
  $rounded_sum += $new_elt;
  $new_arr[] = $new_elt;
}
$orig_sum += $arr[$i];
$expected_rounded_sum = round($orig_sum * $multiplier);
$new_arr[] = $expected_rounded_sum - $rounded_sum;
```

[CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/71ZmKS7K)